# How to ensure an object always is there, even if empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have a jbuilder template which conditionally renders a partial.

```
json.current_user do
  # ...
  json.avatar_urls do
    json.partial! 'api/users/avatar_urls', avatar: user.avatar if user.avatar
  end
end
```

When there is an avatar, the resulting JSON looks like (simplified):

```
"current_user": {
  "avatar_urls": {
    "original": "http://example.com/avatars/example.jpg",
  }
}
```

But, when there is no avatar, the resulting JSON has no "avatar_urls"
object at all:

```
"current_user": {
}
```

I want it to always have this object, but I want it to be an empty
object:

```
"current_user": {
  "avatar_urls": {
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because avatar is returned only when it is not `nil`, so you can make the assumption that if an avatar is nil, you return default object for the avatar.
For example, add somewhere method:

```
def avatar_for(user)
  return user.avatar if user.avatar.present?
  default_avatar
end
```

where `default_avatar` is an object which will be rendered when you invoke

```
json.partial! 'api/users/avatar_urls', avatar: avatar_for(user)
```